# How to run xml in python using DOM APIs if there is more than one attribute

Tags: python, xml

I have a xml code name record.xml which the code is

```
<record>
   <restaurant name="La Pasteria" rate="-">
      <cuisine id="-">Italian</cuisine>
      <address>8, Jalan Mata Kuching, 89200 Selangor</address>
      <capacity>300</capacity>
      <phone>06-2899808</phone>
      <phone>06-2829818</phone>
         <general>-</general>
         <shop1>-</shop1>
         <shop2>-</shop2>
   </restaurant>
   <restaurant name="Nyonya Baba" rate="3">
      <cuisine id="112">Malaysian</cuisine>
      <address>21, Jalan Taming Sari, 75350 Melaka</address>
      <address>25, Jalan Bukit Beruang, 75450 Melaka</address>
      <capacity>80</capacity>
      <phone>
      <general>012-2677498</general>
         <shop1>06-2855413</shop1>
         <shop2>06-2856418</shop2>
      </phone>
   </restaurant>
   <restaurant name="Malaya Food" rate="5">
      <cuisine id="115">Malaysian</cuisine>
      <address>22, Jalan Ayer Keroh, 7520 Melaka</address>
      <capacity>50</capacity>
      <phone>06-2723603</phone>
         <general>-</general>
         <shop1>-</shop1>
         <shop2>-</shop2>
   </restaurant>
</record>
```

As you can see i have a tag name restaurant and attributes which is name and rate, but inside the tag cuisine i also have a attributes which is id.
So when i was running the xml in python, my python code is this

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom

# Open XML document using minidom parser
DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse("record.xml")
collection = DOMTree.documentElement

# Get all the restaurants in the collection
restaurants = collection.getElementsByTagName("restaurant")
ids = collection.getElementsByTagName("cuisine")

# Print detail of each restaurant.
for restaurant in restaurants:
   print ("*****Restaurant*****")
   if restaurant.hasAttribute("name"):
      print ("Name: %s" % restaurant.getAttribute("name"))
      restaurant.hasAttribute("rate")
      print ("Rate: %s" % restaurant.getAttribute("rate"))
   for cuisine in ids:
      print("Cuisine id: %s" % cuisine.getAttribute("id"))

   cuisine = restaurant.getElementsByTagName('cuisine')[0]
   print ("Cuisine: %s" % cuisine.childNodes[0].data)
   address = restaurant.getElementsByTagName('address')[0]
   print ("Address: %s" % address.childNodes[0].data)
   capacity = restaurant.getElementsByTagName('capacity')[0]
   print ("Capacity: %s" % capacity.childNodes[0].data)
   phone = restaurant.getElementsByTagName('phone')[0]
   print ("Phone: %s" % phone.childNodes[0].data)
   general = restaurant.getElementsByTagName('general')[0]
   print ("General: %s" % general.childNodes[0].data)
   shop1 = restaurant.getElementsByTagName('shop1')[0]
   print ("Shop1: %s" % shop1.childNodes[0].data)
   shop2 = restaurant.getElementsByTagName('shop2')[0]
   print ("Shop2: %s" % shop2.childNodes[0].data)
```

And my output is like this

```
*****Restaurant*****
Name: La Pasteria
Rate: -
Cuisine id: -
Cuisine id: 112
Cuisine id: 115
Cuisine: Italian
Address: 8, Jalan Mata Kuching, 89200 Selangor
Capacity: 300
Phone: 06-2899808
General: -
Shop1: -
Shop2: -
*****Restaurant*****
Name: Nyonya Baba
Rate: 3
Cuisine id: -
Cuisine id: 112
Cuisine id: 115
Cuisine: Malaysian
Address: 21, Jalan Taming Sari, 75350 Melaka  
Capacity: 80
Phone: 
      
General: 012-2677498
Shop1: 06-2855413
Shop2: 06-2856418
*****Restaurant*****
Name: Malaya Food
Rate: 5
Cuisine id: -
Cuisine id: 112
Cuisine id: 115
Cuisine: Malaysian
Address: 22, Jalan Ayer Keroh, 7520 Melaka
Capacity: 50
Phone: 06-2723603
General: -
Shop1: -
Shop2: -
PS D:\python file>
```

My cuisine id has stack together, How can i fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line `for cuisine in ids` you're iterating over elements retrieved from the root. Try to use relative path instead:

```
for cuisine in restaurant.getElementsByTagName("cuisine"):
```